# Unable to process files error in gradle checkstyle

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle

I am getting an error when running my gradle checkstyle task.:
`Unable to process files: [(array of files)]`

What's strange is if I reset my changes it works fine. Any ideas?

*UPDATE* I found the line of code causing the issue. It's this line:
`if (!(o instanceof final MyObject that)) {`

This line is using a Java 16 feature, which compiles for me as that is the java version I am using. However, it seems to cause checkstyle to break.
When I convert this line to traditional Java (without the variable declaration), checkstyle works fine.
This seems broken, anyone experience this?

Comment: Please add checkstyle version you are using. Probably it is old and does not support recent grammar changes.

Answer (score 0):

Running the same problem.
I solved it by excluding the module-info.java from been scanned by checkstyle.
in build.gradle.kts I added checkstyle configuration:

```
tasks.withType<Checkstyle>().configureEach {
config = resources.text.fromFile("${project.rootProject.rootDir.path}/${System.getProperty("checkstyleInputDir")}/checkstyle.xml");
configDirectory.set(file("${project.rootProject.rootDir.path}/${System.getProperty("checkstyleInputDir")}"));
ignoreFailures = true;
reports {
    xml.required.set(true);
    html.required.set(false);
}
exclude("**/module-info.java");
}
```

look at the line: *exclude("**/module-info.java");*.
This will make checkstyle to skip the module files.